# Windows Driver unload pending

Tags: windows, device-driver

I am writing a driver (legacy I believe) that creates a virtual hard drive from a file, however when I try to unload my driver some times it and most times it hangs. The driver unloads cleanly if it hasn't received any irps yet but as soon as it does I can't unload it.  have read that the unload routine isn't called unless the driver has nothing referencing it. I believe there may be another driver(a file system driver) referencing it however I don't know which driver it is. How can I see if my driver is getting referenced and if so how can i stop that driver from referencing mine?

Comment: Not enough details to give you an answer.  Was your `DriverUnload` routine called?  Did your driver receive `irp_mn_stop_device`?  Did you try to find stacks with your driver on the stack (e.g. `!stacks 0 YourDriverNameHere`)?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "HandleCount" and "PointerCount" of your driver's "DriverObject" and "DeviceObject" using windbg.

Useful Windbg commands are: !drvobj  and !devobj.